# docx4j simulate expression evaluation

Tags: docx4j

I have a docx document with some formulas, e.g.

{IF "Name" = "Foo" "Foo" "Bar"}

which should print "Bar" at the end.

In Word I have to press "F9" to get the expression evaluated.
No I am using docx4j, can I somehow tell docx4j to do the evaluation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not.  You can get the expression of course (see [this discussion](http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/parsing-of-form-fields-in-word-document-t2118.html) about some classes which help), but there is currently nothing in docx4j to evaluate an [IF field](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/IF.html) for you.

If the objective is to include/exclude text, you'll be able to achieve the same end with an OpenDoPE conditional content control (based on whether an XPath evaluates to true or false). (docx4j can evaluate these; they can also be nested, to support complex content)